# Common approach of sending sensitive data between pages asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, razor-pages, sensitive-data

I went through many articles regarding sending data between pages in asp.net core. Most of the issues are old or listing the mechanisms for retaining data "Hidden form fields, query-string, Temp data, sessions" in a general way, I need to understand when to use them and in which situation.

In my situation, I have a list of records page and links to each record details page. The common approach here in ASP.NET Core to `asp-route-{value}` in the anchor tag which will send the data as query parameters but the ID to be sent to another page is sensitive so I need to hide it from the user. My question here is there any built-in asp.net core mechanism for this situation .. I don't want to build other solutions like encrypting the data or whatever if there is a common approach for sending the data with GET Request.

Another point that caught my attention, I read in one of the articles that in the Post case is not preferable to send hidden fields for sensitive data, so what is the approach as well for the POST method.

Comment: Server side storage should be secure - e.g. session, database

Comment: I've covered all the ways to retain state across requests, how to use them and when here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management